# simplify jQuery selector highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have over 100 videos and I use a function to highlight the links clicked. The code thought is very long and I feel like there must be a way to simplify it into a for loop or something. Any idea?

```
var vid_all0 = $('#vid_link0, #vidtop_link0, .vidtop_link0, #vidmob_link0, #link0');     //cache selector

vid_all0.click(function () {        
    $('[id^=vid_link],[id^=vidtop_link],[id^=vidmob_link], .vidtop_link0').css('background-color', 'inherit');
    vid_all0.css('background-color', '#A9CDEB'); //change color of all elements
    $('.vidtop_link0').css('background-color', 'inherit');
});

var vid_all1 = $('#vid_link1, #vidtop_link1, #vidmob_link1,#link10'); //cache selector

vid_all1.click(function () {        
    $('[id^=vid_link],[id^=vidtop_link],[id^=vidmob_link]').css('background-color', 'inherit');
    vid_all1.css('background-color', '#A9CDEB'); //change color of all elements
});

var vid_all2 = $('#vid_link2, #vidtop_link2, #vidmob_link2,#link19'); //cache selector

vid_all2.click(function () {        
    $('[id^=vid_link],[id^=vidtop_link],[id^=vidmob_link]').css('background-color', 'inherit');
    vid_all2.css('background-color', '#A9CDEB'); //change color of all elements
});
```

...
it goes up to 15

Comment: can you post some html ?

Comment: why use a for loop?just highlight the one clicked by detecting the id onclick of your element..

Comment: The jquery selectors are suitable for loop: e.g. why there is `,.vidtop_link0` in `vid_all0.click` - first line (next click events haven't it)? And what with `#link0, #link10, #link19` sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Give all those elements the same class, then use all elements with that class like

```
$(".vidtop").on("click", function()
{
    // Do something with their CSS
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify your HTML with a class, something like this should work:

```
for (var i=1; i=99; i==;) {
    $(vid_all + i).click(function () {        
        $(this).find('[id^=vid_link],[id^=vidtop_link],[id^=vidmob_link]').css('background-color', 'inherit');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your code correctly, but this would seem to be a simpler version:

```
function doStuff(links, additional) {
    links.click(function() {
        $('[id^=vid_link],[id^=vidtop_link],[id^=vidmob_link]' + (additional ? "," + additional : "")).css('background-color', 'inherit');
        links.css('background-color', '#A9CDEB');
        if (additional) {
            additional.css('background-color', 'inherit');
        }       
    });
}

// vid_all0
doStuff($('#vid_link0, #vidtop_link0, .vidtop_link0, #vidmob_link0, #link0'), $('.vidtop_link0'));
// vid_all1
doStuff($('#vid_link1, #vidtop_link1, #vidmob_link1,#link10'));
// vid_all2
doStuff($('#vid_link2, #vidtop_link2, #vidmob_link2,#link19'));
// etc.
```